# Routing for Lightning network: was Flare implemented?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing

There is a 2016 paper from Bitfury on a proposed routing algorithm for LN:

[Flare: An Approach to Routing
in Lightning Network](https://bitfury.com/content/downloads/whitepaper_flare_an_approach_to_routing_in_lightning_network_7_7_2016.pdf)

What is the relation between it and was was actually implemented (the primary reference being the [BOLT specs](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/00-introduction.md))?

Comment: It was implemented by Bitfury and Acinq, but only for testing purposes, it never went to the production implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know flare was never implemented for lightning nodes and is not being used. I think current implementations use sind pathfinding algorithms like BfS or  Dijkstra. The pathfinding itself is not part of the BOLTs anyway. A node could do whatever it wants with the information provided from the gossip store / gossip protocol. (BOLT 07). People could in particular decide to go for the approach given by flare.